# Multiples threads in FTP download: give each its own connection Vs. have them share one connection

Tags: java, multithreading, ftp, connection, ftp-server

In an application that downloads several files from an FTP server, it uses threads, ie. 5, to do its deed, and each one has its own connection (Apache Commons FTPClient.connect(url)).

Will it be the same if the connection is shared instead? Is the ability to download files simultaneously be affected? Does the number of connections also dictate how well the app can maximize bandwidth (like maybe because an FTP server configure a bandwidth limit per connection it accepts, if there is such a thing)?

Comment: AFAIK, standard FTP does not support multiple streams on either the control or data connection.  The only way I have done anything like this is to use a separate FTP client instance, and hence connection, for each thread.  A single large- file FTP transfer is usually bandwidth limited and so a multithreaded transfer only helps much if there are a lot of small files, (so mitigating connect/disconnect latency), eg. when listing a folder tree on the server.  I have not investigated the effect with bandwidth-limited servers.

Comment: You should promote your comment to be an answer @Martin.

Comment: Hi Martin, i would like to accept your answer, if you get a chance please promote the commment to an answer.